# WordPress: Get taxonomies used in custom query result

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy

I want to list a every taxonomy which is used in the output of a custom query.

For example:

I have a couple of cars listed on my site and a custom query to get all SUVs from that list. For that I'm using the following query args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'cars' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'car_type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'suv',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $query->posts;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    $term_objects = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'brand' );

    foreach ( $term_objects as $term_object ) {
        $terms_list[ $term_object->name ] = $term_object;
    }
}
```

With this query I get a list of all SUVs within my cars.

Now I want to show a list of **brands**. The brand is a also a custom taxonomy.

So let's say there are 50 cars as a result from my query from 5 different brands.
How could I filter my query result and get the IDs of every brand (only once per brand) within the query results.

Comment: Loop over the posts this got you, and put the value of the brand taxonomy of the posts into an array ... Use array_unique afterwards to filter out duplicate entries, or build your array in a way so that you don't add them in the first place (for example using the brand ID as array key, then you can simply check if that key is set, before you add the data for the current brand.)

Comment: Hmm, I tried to use your hints to build a working function. But I failed :-( Could you post a sample function maybe?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I edited my question with my code. I get the brands from it but not sure yet how to store them as unique IDs.

Comment: With `$terms_list[ $term_object->name ] = $term_object;` you are already storing them in a unique way, because when you encounter a specific term name for the second time, the existing entry unter `$terms_list[$term_object->name ]` will be overwritten. If there could be multiple different terms with the exact same name, then you could also use the term ID instead of the name as the array index, but that should probably not be necessary.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I still get every term even if they were already stored.

If I do this: `$items = $terms_list[ $term_object->ID ] = $term_object;` and print them out with this (after foreach): `print_r($items);` I still get every term multiple times.

Comment: That makes no sense, if you got `$items = ...`, you would be _overwriting_ the content of that variable every single time, so you could not have an array in this afterwards to begin with, but only one single item.

Comment: Okay, I tried evreything I could think of with my limited understanding of PHP. Unfortunately I'm stuck. Could you give me a hint how to store the IDs in a array which I could use?

Comment: It is hard to help, as long as what you say is happening is still logically inconsistent. What's with this `$items = ...` stuff, that does not make sense to begin with. Check what `$terms_list` contains, after _both_ of the loops have finished.

Comment: That's it... Thank you! I was inside the first loop... now everything works fine. If you want, you can put that as answer and I will accept it and delete the comments to keep the site clean.